Replace an empty element
As a part of my workflow I am receiving xml files, sometimes a specific element is empty and this leads to problems in the system, this is a sample input file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompositionPlaylist xmlns="http://www.xml.com/20040511#">
    <Id>urn:uuid:129de837-6eed-40d4-a635-db58380dfd9e</Id>
    <AnnotationText>Title</AnnotationText>
    <IssueDate>2014-09-22T19:18:56.001+01:00</IssueDate>
    <Issuer>issuer</Issuer>
    <Creator>Creator Name</Creator>
    <ContentTitleText>Content Title</ContentTitleText>
    <ContentKind>feature</ContentKind>
     <ContentVersion>
    <Id>urn:uuid:e52a4259-ecad-4630-be51-cf13f95d8b82</Id>
    <LabelText>Title of the media</LabelText>
  </ContentVersion>
    <RatingList/>
    <ReelList>
        <Reel>
            <Id>urn:uuid:1b840b2b-7526-4597-ae2d-81994f8e9867</Id>
            <AnnotationText>FeG_r1_new</AnnotationText>
            <AssetList>
                <MainPicture>
                    <Id>urn:uuid:e6ac03bd-65a5-4dab-bb24-682c6b5bf61a</Id>
                    <EditRate>24 1</EditRate>
                    <IntrinsicDuration>25965</IntrinsicDuration>
                    <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
                    <Duration>25965</Duration>
                    <Hash>3VTtxrGsVs1AsE4JXU12wdF/U0o=</Hash>
                    <FrameRate>24 1</FrameRate>
                    <ScreenAspectRatio>1.77</ScreenAspectRatio>
                </MainPicture>
                <MainSound>
                    <Id>urn:uuid:1202f14c-13ce-4585-8a3f-fd489b6c6bac</Id>
                    <EditRate>24 1</EditRate>
                    <IntrinsicDuration>25990</IntrinsicDuration>
                    <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
                    <Duration>25965</Duration>
                    <Hash>cU4riXDJwfsQ9rL7tkd0c8nZgWw=</Hash>
                    <Language>und</Language>
                </MainSound>
            </AssetList>
        </Reel>

sometimes the element "ContentVersion" is empty like this:
    <ContentVersion>
        <LabelText/>
    </ContentVersion

it would be fine to replace the element with a "dummy" one, like this
    <ContentVersion>
    <Id>urn:uuid:11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</Id>
    <LabelText>DUMMY</LabelText>
    </ContentVersion>

Steps Taken
Tried XSLT transform but could not find a way to replace the full element with cild

An empty element looks like <ContentVersion></ContentVersion> or <ContentVersion/>. Your ContentVersion element is certainly not empty, it contains a LabelText element which is empty.

A request for someone to write your code for you is not a legitimate question.

I'm not sure exactly what you want to test when you say that ContentVersion must not be empty, but for example if your test is that it must have a non-empty LabelText, then your XSLT transformation could do
<xsl:template match="ContentVersion[not(LabelText) or LabelText = '']">
  <ContentVersion>
    <Id>urn:uuid:11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</Id>
    <LabelText>DUMMY</LabelText>
  </ContentVersion>
</xsl:template>

Adjust the predicate to your taste if your definition of "emptiness" is different.

thank you for the answer, I have tried this but it does not change the output xml, I found other two more options that can be suitable : delete the element "ContentVersion" with all possible child elements -  2 Replace the same element with the "dummy" sample, no matter if is empty or not

@ago1965, keep in mind that your XML input uses a default namespace (e.g. xmlns="http://www.xml.com/20040511#" so for the above code to work as posted you need to use an XSLT 2 or later processor and make sure the XSLT stylesheet declared e.g. xpath-default-namespace="http://www.xml.com/20040511#". For an XSLT 1 processor you need your XSLT to declare a prefix for that namespace (e.g. xmlns:ns1="http://www.xml.com/20040511#" and use e.g. <xsl:template match="ns1:ContentVersion[not(ns1:LabelText) or ns1:LabelText = '']">.

@ago1965, also keep in mind that the posted snippet is just taken care of the particular insertion you want to make, it is supposed to be used in the context of an identity transformation (declared in XSLT 3 with <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> or in previous versions of XSLT with the template <xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template> included in your XSLT).

thank you Martin and Michael, all answers were very helpful
